# How do I convert a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, split

I would like to parse the following text file into a dictionary:

```
Train A
Travelled 150km
No longer in use
Stored in warehouse 

Train B
Travelled 100km
Used by X company
Daily usage
Actively upgrading
```

The end result dictionary should have `Train A` and `Train B` as keys, and the rest of values as list of values:

```
{
'Train A': ['Travelled 150km', 'No longer in use', 'Stored in warehouse'], 
'Train B': ['Travelled 100km', 'Used by X company', 'Daily usage', 'Actively upgrading']
}
```

I've currently tried

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    dict = {}
    for i in data:
        key = i[0]
        value = i[1:]
        d[key] = value
print(dict)
```

Really not too sure where im wrong. I want to split the \n after Train A, where Train A is Key and all the other information listed is the value

Comment: This is a simple programming exercise. What have you tried? Please include your code.

Comment: @DYZ tried this but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Your units are separated by blank lines - so, you should first split by two newlines, not by one. The following implementation is somewhat inefficient (it splits the same variable twice), but it works, and you can improve it if you want:

```
[{x.split("\n")[0]: x.split("\n")[1:]} for x in data.split("\n\n")]
#[{'Train A': ['Travelled 150km', 'No longer in use', 
#  'Stored in warehouse']}, 
# {'Train B': ['Travelled 100km', 'Used by X company', 
#  'Daily usage', 'Actively upgrading'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You need to split the files using empty line first (`'\n\n'`), then continue on with your idea.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n\n') # <=== this is what's missing
    print(data)
    d = {}
    for i in data:
        i = i.split('\n')
        key = i[0]
        value = i[1:]
        d[key] = value
print(d)
```